# ldd reports not a single dependency, even when at least one library is missing

Tags: command-line, bash, dependencies

The ldd on my system is a *script*:

```
$ ldd --version
ldd (GNU libc) 2.35
Copyright (C) 2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Written by Roland McGrath and Ulrich Drepper.

$ file /usr/bin/ldd
/usr/bin/ldd: Bourne-Again shell script, ASCII text executable

$ head -n 29 /usr/bin/ldd|tail
# This is the `ldd' command, which lists what shared libraries are
# used by given dynamically-linked executables.  It works by invoking the
# run-time dynamic linker as a command and setting the environment
# variable LD_TRACE_LOADED_OBJECTS to a non-empty value.

# We should be able to find the translation right at the beginning.
TEXTDOMAIN=libc
TEXTDOMAINDIR=/usr/share/locale

RTLDLIST="/lib/ld-linux.so.2 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /libx32/ld-linux-x32.so.2"
```

At times, it fails to report anything, especially annoying when I try to figure out what dependencies are missing for a certain program.

Like today with evince

```
$ ldd /usr/bin/evince

$ evince
evince: error while loading shared libraries: libhandy-1.so.0: cannot open
shared object file: No such file or directory
```

*Any idea why ldd reports nothing?* I know from past experiences with this issue that *when I solved the 1st missing dependency* (in this case: installing libhandy-1.so.0) *then ldd would show the list of dependencies*, including listing possible several other missing libraries.
**But I want ldd to work correctly from the very beginning.**
Sadly I have no clue how to fix that since ldd looks too complex a script for me to easily understand, and since it reports nothing at all I have not even a hint where it went wrong.

Comment: What happens if you run it this way: `LD_TRACE_LOADED_OBJECTS=1 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /usr/bin/evince` ? That's what actually `/usr/bin/ldd` is calling, you can add `set -x` to the ldd bash script in order to debug it.

Comment: @mestia Thanks for that info. `$ LD_TRACE_LOADED_OBJECTS=1 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /usr/bin/evince
Segmentation fault` That explains the issue why ldd is not reporting anything, seems the SegFault is omitted.